# if condition within animate

Tags: if-statement, scroll, jquery-animate, mouseover

I am using the code from the folling link on mouseover function
http://perplexed.co.uk/1991_jquery_scroll_tabs_like_browser_tabs.htm

i check the values of offset during mouseover and set the visibility prev and next button. But the checking always happens in the next mouseover .
Eg: i have to set the next button to invisible during the same mouse over event  when i scroll and reach the end. but it happens in the next mouseover.

Is it posiible to write an if function within the animate function

Comment: Yes, didn't you try first ?

Comment: No. but what s the syntax for it ?

Comment: (didYouTry)?'You should have found it by now':'You can start trying now';

Comment: I tried. But it doesnt work. it again happens in the next mouseover.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is. I changed the script you used from 'click' to 'mouseover' and it just works. No need to add any if statement. Just change the `.click` parts like this:

```
$(".slider").off('mouseover', '.next').on('mouseover', '.next', function(){
...
}
$(".slider").off('mouseover', '.prev').on('mouseover', '.prev', function(){
...
}
```

Demonstration at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AwfKr/)

Comment: Yes i wanted it to happen on the first hover. I used setinterval to check the values of offset for the button to go invisible and it worked. :) thanks a lot.