# syntax of if condition within animate of jquery

Tags: jquery, if-statement, tabs, jquery-animate, conditional-statements

How do i write if condition within animate for the following?

```
 $($("#tabs > ul"), $(this).parent()).animate({
                    marginLeft: '+=' + marginleft
                }, '10000', 'swing');
```

Comment: if (offset >= maxoffset) {
                    $('#tabs').find('button.gnnext').css('visibility', 'hidden');

I have chceck the above condition during animation to diable the next button when i reach last tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could fit your need:

*As IDs must be unique on context page, that selector is better*

```
$("#tabs > ul").animate({
    marginLeft: '+=' + marginleft
}, {
    step: function (fx) {
       if(someCondition)
           $(this).stop(true);
    }
},
    '10000',
    'swing');
```

Or for more global condition, use @billyonecan's answer

Comment: Thank you. i tried it. I need this for the following query


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17542353/if-condition-within-animate

I am not able to achieve it using this . But this helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you can use the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
$($("#tabs > ul"), $(this).parent()).animate({
    marginLeft: (condition ? 'value if true' : 'value if false')
}, '10000', 'swing');
```

Comment: I want to check the value of offset and max offset and compare so that i can change the visbility of the button based on position of the tabs.